# Cannot add an account to SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server, iis, sql-server-2012

Background:

I have a application pool [ABCDEMO] in IIS. The identity of the appool is "NetworkService". I am trying to add IIS APPPOOL\ABCDEMO to my SQL SERVER 2012 on a Windows SERVER 2012.

When I try to add to the Logins I get the following error.

```
===================================

Create failed for Login 'IIS APPPOOL\ABCDEMO'.  (Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft+SQL+Server&ProdVer=11.0.2100.60+((SQL11_RTM).120210-1917+)&EvtSrc=Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExceptionTemplates.FailedOperationExceptionText&EvtID=Create+Login&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLoginData.LoginPrototype.ApplyGeneralChanges(Server server)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlManagerUI.CreateLogin.DoPreProcessExecution(RunType runType, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.DoPreProcessExecutionAndRunViews(RunType runType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.ExecuteForSql(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.SqlMgmtTreeViewControl.Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.IExecutionAwareSqlControlCollection.PreProcessExecution(PreProcessExecutionInfo executionInfo, ExecutionMode& executionResult)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlMgmt.ViewSwitcherControlsManager.RunNow(RunType runType, Object sender)

===================================

An exception occurred while executing a Transact-SQL statement or batch. (Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo)

------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection sqlCommands, ExecutionTypes executionType)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.ExecutionManager.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.ExecuteNonQuery(StringCollection queries, Boolean includeDbContext)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImplFinish(StringCollection createQuery, ScriptingPreferences sp)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.SqlSmoObject.CreateImpl()

===================================

Windows NT user or group 'IIS APPPOOL\ABCDEMO' not found. Check the name again. (.Net SqlClient Data Provider)

------------------------------
For help, click: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink?ProdName=Microsoft%20SQL%20Server&ProdVer=11.00.2100&EvtSrc=MSSQLServer&EvtID=15401&LinkId=20476

------------------------------
Server Name: USALVWCOQA10
Error Number: 15401
Severity: 16
State: 1
Line Number: 1


------------------------------
Program Location:

   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ConnectionManager.ExecuteTSql(ExecuteTSqlAction action, Object execObject, DataSet fillDataSet, Boolean catchException)
   at Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Common.ServerConnection.ExecuteNonQuery(String sqlCommand, ExecutionTypes executionType)
```

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Why do you need to add this account? What is it for?

Comment: You don't need to add app pool accounts to SQL.  If anything, you should have a domain level service account for the App Pool identity in IIS and then leverage that account in SQL.

Comment: Do you really have a domain named "*IIS APPPOOL*"? I don't think that I've ever seen a domain name with a space in it.  I doubt that SQL Server is going to be happy with that.

Answer (score 0):

Are the IIS box and the SQL server on the same physical machine?

If they are, and your app pool is running as Network Service, you can add:

'NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE'

If they are running on separate machines, then the account that NETWORK SERVICE uses to authenticate to the network is the domain account of the server itself, in which case you should add the machine account of the IIS server to the SQL server as so:

'DOMAIN\IISSERVERNAME$'

Obviously substitute your domain and the hostname of the IIS server in there, the dollar sign is important though.